# Mysqli_stmt Erros

Tags: php, mysqli

Olá,

Tenho este código

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "../extras/config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$grupo = $cliente = "";
$grupo_err = $cliente_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])){
    // Get hidden input value
    $id = $_POST["id"];

// Valida grupo
    $input_grupo = trim($_POST["grupo"]);
    if(empty($input_grupo)){
        $grupo_err = "Por favor introduza um grupo";
    } elseif(!ctype_digit($input_grupo)){
        $grupo_err = "Por favor introduza um cliente válido";
    } else{
        $grupo = $input_grupo;
    }

    // Valida cliente
    $input_cliente = trim($_POST["cliente"]);
    if(empty($input_cliente)){
        $cliente_err = "Por favor introduza um cliente";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_cliente, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $cliente_err = "Por favor introduza um cliente válido";
    } else{
        $cliente = $input_cliente;
    }

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($grupo_err) && empty($cliente_err)){
        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "UPDATE clientes SET id_grupo=?, cliente=?, WHERE id=?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $param_grupo, $param_cliente, $param_id);

            // Set parameters
            $param_grupo = $grupo;
            $param_cliente = $cliente;
            $param_id = $id;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: clientes.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Algo está errado. Por favor tente novamente mais tarde.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
    if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
        // Get URL parameter
        $id =  trim($_GET["id"]);

        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente = ?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);

            // Set parameters
            $param_id = $id;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                    /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set
                    contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                    // Retrieve individual field value
                    $grupo = $row["id_grupo"];
                    $cliente = $row["cliente"];

                } else{
                    // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                    header("location: erro.php");
                    exit();
                }

            } else{
                echo "Oops! Algo está errado. Por favor tente novamente mais tarde.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($link);
    }  else{
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: erro.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Actualizar Registo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h2>Actualizar Registo</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p>Por favor actualize os registos e registe para actualizar.</p>
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($grupo_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($grupo_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Grupo</label>
                            &nbsp
                            <?php

                            $host="localhost";
                            $user="root";
                            $pass="";
                            $dbname="adminam";

                            $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);

                            $query="SELECT * FROM grupos";

                            $result1=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

                            ?>

                            <select name="grupo" style="width: 100%">

                            <?php while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result1)): ?>

                            <option name="grupo" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><?php echo $row[1];?></option>option>

                            <?php endwhile; ?>

                            </select>
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $grupo_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($cliente_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Cliente</label>
                            <input type="text" name="cliente" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $cliente; ?>">
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $cliente_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Actualizar">
                        <a href="clientes.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Estou sempre a receber a mensagem

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\final\ges_clientes\update.php on line 59
```

O que está errado? Este código funcionava ainda ontem...apenas alterei os campos...
Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inicialmente, o erro está aqui:

```
[...]
if(empty($grupo_err) && empty($cliente_err)){
    // Prepare an update statement
    $sql = "UPDATE clientes SET id_grupo=?, cliente=?, WHERE id=?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
[...]
```

Sua *query* tem uma vírgula sobrando: `[...] cliente=?, WHERE id [...]`.

Ela deve ficar assim:

```
$sql = "UPDATE clientes SET id_grupo=?, cliente=? WHERE id=?";
```

---

Outra questão é na estrutura do seu `if`:

```
    [...]
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        [...]
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
[...]
```

A função `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);` deveria estar dentro do `if`, de forma que ela só seja chamada **se** o *statement* for "preparado". Da forma que está, ela acaba tentando fechar o *statement* mesmo sem haver tal. O que acabou gerando o erro mencionado.

Veja como fica:

```
    [...]
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        [...]
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

}
[...]
```

---

Para finalizar, considere adicionar um `else` retornando uma mensagem que ocorreu um erro:

```
    [...]
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        [...]
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    } else die('Erro: falha no db!');

}
[...]
```

A função `die()` vai parar a execução do script.

Comment: Obrigado, a virgula fez mesmo a diferença! 
Quanto ás restantes notas vou ter as mesmas em consideração e fazer as respectivas alterações, obrigado pelas dicas!

Comment: No que se refere ao erro, considere todas as dicas que mencionei na resposta. Não limite-se apenas a essa vírgula. ;)